# Greasemonkey - jQuery not loading

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I tried to load a copy of jQuery 1.3.2 from jquery.com (because it seems 1.4.0+ aren't treated too well by GM) using `@require`.

Even after I uninstall and reinstall the script, GM does not copy jquery-1.3.2.js to my gm_scripts folder like it should. Tried this almost 10 times today.

Also, when I click on "Manage Scripts", it shows my script as running on `*` even though I've added @include for `http://www.catholicon.in/*`

I'm using the latest updates on both FF 3.6 and GM 0.8

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the headers of your script (you don't need the post the whole script) so we can test it to see what the problem might be?

Answer (score -1):

Try following this: http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/ 
It has been suggested that there is a problem with jquery and so this may also help:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/importing-jquery-1-4-1-into-greasemonkey-scripts-generates-an-error

Comment: This is obsolete as of GM version 0.9.